# Simplify two functions with same functionalities?

Tags: javascript, triggers, simplify, debouncing, mouseleave

I have two functions that do the same thing, but are used differently.

I currently have a popup that is triggered on actions based on device. On desktop, if the mouse leaves the page, it triggers the popup (function called `exitUserMessage`). On mobile, if the mouse is inactive for 10 seconds+ it triggers the popup (function called `inactiveUserMessage`). See below:

```
    //display popup for inactive users
        const inactiveUserMessage = () => {
        //other code was here but deleted bc not relevant
            return dismissModal();
        };
    
        //display popup for users leaving the page
        function exitUserMessage() {
        //other code was here but deleted bc not relevant
            return dismissModal();
        }
```

Here is where the functions are used, both separately for desktop and mobile:

```
    if (width <= 480) {
        // Start the timer on page load
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            timer = setTimeout(inactiveUserMessage, 10000);
        });
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", debounce(inactiveUserMessage, 10000), timer);
    } else {
        // Trigger popup for desktop
        document.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
            if (Evergage.cashDom("#abandon-cart-message").length === 0) {
                return exitUserMessage();
            }
        });
    }
```

`inactiveUserMessage` is used in the debounce function that delays it by 10 seconds, then triggers the popup to show.

`exitUserMessage` is returned when the mouse leaves the page for desktop. My question is both of these functions are doing the same thing above ^.

Any ways to simplify? I am fairly new to JavaScript so looking to learn best practice!

Something worth noting: these are tracked as separate actions in our dataLayer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `inactiveUserMessage` variable like functions. If there are different parts in those functions, add a parameter like `isDesktop` to `inactiveUserMessage` and `debounce` functions . If true, run the relevant desktop code in `if` statement.

```js
const inactiveUserMessage = (isDesktop) => {
  if (isDestop) {
    //Desktop
  } else {
    //Mobile
  }

  return dismissModal();
};



if (width <= 480) {
  // Start the timer on page load
  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    timer = setTimeout(inactiveUserMessage, 10000);
  });
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", debounce(inactiveUserMessage, false, 10000), timer);
} else {
  // Trigger popup for desktop
  document.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
    if (Evergage.cashDom("#abandon-cart-message").length === 0) {
      return inactiveUserMessage(true);
    }
  });
}
```